# How to get yesterday's date all files by using Talend?

Tags: java, talend

I have tried like this, I'm adding

```
TalendDate.compareDate(row1.filepath, context.myStartDate, 'yyyy-Mm-dd')>0 && TalendDate.comparDate(row1.filepath, context.EndDate, 'yyyy-Mm-dd')<3
```

Adding like this in `tMap`

Can anyone help me to get yesterday's date files by using `Talend`?

Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: What do you mean by "yesterday's date files"? You mean files created yesterday?

Comment: Yes files created yesterday..

Comment: Are they named or arranged in a certain way, or is the only indicator you have that they were created yesterday their creation timestamp of the file system?
You can get yesterdays date itself with LocalDate.now().minusDays(1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE)

Answer (score 0):

Use tFileExist and tFlowToIterate to check and loop all the files.